# error Opencv 3 in python 3.6.4

Tags: python, opencv, module

I'm just getting started to learning opencv on python
I'm using win 10, python 3.6.4 and opencv 3.4
when i want to run this code

```
image = cv2.imread("lena.jpg")

height, width = image.shape[:2]

quarter_height, quarter_width = height/4, width/4

T = np.float32([[1, 0, quarter_height], [0, 1, quarter_width]])
img_translation = cv2.wrapAffine(image, T, (width, height))
cv2.imshow("Translate", img_translation)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

this error raised

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\...\PyCharm 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydev_run_in_console.py", line 
52, 
in run_file
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
File "C:\...\PyCharm 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", 
line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "C:/Projects/P03/Program.py", line 20, in <module>
main()
File "C:/Projects/P03/Program.py", line 13, in main
img_translation = cv2.wrapAffine(image, T, (width, height))
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'wrapAffine'
```

but when i see in dir(cv2)
i can find wrapAffine function

i do know how to solve this problem
i tried to run the code on several IDEs and python console
but nothing happened.
please help

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your code, or maybe a misunderstanding of the correct term.

> The function is **[`warpAffine`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga0203d9ee5fcd28d40dbc4a1ea4451983)**, *not* `wrapAffine`.

Answer (score 2):

```
  wrapAffine(image, T, (width, height))
```

The function is `warpAffine`. 
This function apply a affine transformation to the image

Comment: why downvoted I don't think their is anything wrong in the answer.

Comment: This answer is correct, yet somebody downvoted it. When is SO going to request that a downvote needs to be explained?

Comment: @JeruLuke: I don't think someone even has to have a reason; I assume this was downvoted because it's basically no different than my answer,  or maybe something else is missing.

Comment: but sir if a question have two same answer that doesn't means I am copying your answer.

Comment: @ChandrapalSinghJhala Once in a while you'll get some odd downvotes (just as there are tons of odd upvotes happening as well) -- someone just didn't consider it useful, that's life, and there's little point arguing about it. Get over it and move on, the few points are absolutely meaningless in the long run.

Comment: I am not against the downvotes sir, but the person should still mention the valid reason behind that. So, that I keep that in mind while answering and try to improve that in future.

Comment: @ChandrapalSinghJhala I get what you mean, what I'm saying is that the person who did that is unlikely to come back, so there's nothing you can do about it... just let it go. (I rarely go back to what I consider garbage posts i downvote, since I'm rarely interested in spending more effort on explaining what wrong than the author took to post). I've had correct answers downvoted due to used changing the question later. Much more elaborate posts (with hours spent tutoring the OP over chat, and worked examples provided) downvoted for no obvious reason. Meh, who cares.

Comment: @ChandrapalSinghJhala To be constructive, what you could improve with this post... First of all, notice that the other answer provides a link to the documentation of the function. That's a plus. | To be honest, I'd close the question since it's a simple type, but let's say we want to answer it... what would make it even better. Well, you could provide a full, corrected example script that works, along with a picture of the output that proves that it does. | I'd also explicitly mention that the user made a typo -- it's much more obvious from the wording of the other answer here.